# Bootstrap4 using card-primary to achieve inverse effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need to use cards with an inverse effect. Card-primary class with $blue:#363636 works perfect for me. Unfortunately, a standard Card-primary has a blue background while I need to have it while. I did try card-inverse but it's not what I need exactly. The background is too dark. How would I go about solving my problem?

Thanks

Update.
Actually I was wrong inverse makes everything white: text and a background.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `outline` card variation...

```
    <div class="card card-outline-primary text-primary">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Outline</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/eQoWW5JVzO

The `text-primary` isn't necessary unless you want blue text too.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Is there a single source of information that would help to understand how B4 classes can be combined?

Comment: I don't really know of one, specifically, other than the [official docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com).